# Library "Generate-password" stop working with latest NODE.js deployment

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am beginner in node.Js, React and here in this forum.

I installed latest node.JS package and my app-web in React stopped working and receive this error. :(

Compiled with problems:

**ERROR in** ./src/components/grid/customGrid.jsx 313:25-43

export 'default' (imported as 'generator') was not found in 'generate-password' (possible exports: __esModule, generate, generateMultiple)

**ERROR in** ./node_modules/generate-password/src/generate.js 1:0-53

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\app-web\node_modules\generate-password\src'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
- install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }

I would like to say thanks for the solution.

I am expecting a solution from specialists.

Comment: Take a look at generate-password Github repo,  [here](https://github.com/brendanashworth/generate-password/issues/68)